# CORS error между фронтендом и бэкендом

Tags: php, reactjs, cors

Есть фронтенд на react.js стоящий на http://localhost:3000 в котором через `axios` отправляется запрос на удалённый бэкенд сервер (работает на https)(Laravel 8) но он заканчивается ошибкой Cors error.

На бэкенде вроде бы правильно прописаны заголовки.
вот заголовки ответа от сервера.

```
access-control-allow-headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 1728000
cache-control: no-cache, private
connection: keep-alive
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 04 Aug 2021 10:44:42 GMT
server: nginx/1.16.1
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-powered-by: PHP/7.1.33
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: access-control-allow-headers и access-control-allow-methods вроде излишние? зачем всем разрешать access-control-allow-origin - дай разрешение на один источник.

Comment: @Jean-Claude а как это написать access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000 ??? так?

Comment: точно не подскажу, попробуй просто http:// localhost но вообще на локалхосте у меня виртуальные домены